# converting raw sql query to a laravel eloquent model

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I've been trying to convert the following query to an eloquent model query/raw database query. I have limited knowledge of laravel and I've come to a stop.

```
 select 
                status, 
                (SELECT count(*) FROM active_call_statuses WHERE active_call_id = 'CA3a77245ab0eac10f8cf3aa8e7c8f9a91') AS total 
            from 
                active_call_statuses
            left JOIN
                active_calls ON active_calls.parent_call_id = active_call_statuses.active_call_id
            where 
                status IN('in-progress', 'completed', 'ringing', 'answered', 'busy', 'failed', 'no-answer')
            and 
                active_calls.parent_call_id = 'CA3a77245ab0eac10f8cf3aa8e7c8f9a91'
```

the pupose of the query is to select all columns with the given call status and count the total of status entries associated to the current call via its id in a sub query.

The query does what it's supposed to in mysql as far as i can see but I dont know how to convert this to an eloquent query.

The active_call_statuses table and active_calls table are linked to eachother via a one-to-many relationship on parent_call_id in eloquent respectively like so.

```
class ActiveCall extends Model

{
    /**
     * @var mixed
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
 * @var array fillable properties
 */
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'conference_id', 'parent_call_id'];

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function statuses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('app\ActiveCallStatus');
}
}



  class ActiveCallStatus extends Model
{
/**
 * @var bool timestamps enabled
 */
public $timestamps = false;

/**
 * @var array fillable properties
 */
protected $fillable = ['active_call_id', 'user_id', 'status'];

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function activeCall()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('app\ActiveCall');
}
}
```

I've tried wraping the query in a `DB::select` with a `DB::raw`, calling a table with the `DB->table(...)->selectRaw(...) .etc` method by binding the parameters to the `selectRaw aliased with :id` but everything resulted in database errors `invalid parameter number` or other errors.

This is my last attempt:

```
processedUsers = DB::table('active_call_statuses')->select(
                    DB::raw("
                        SELECT
                        user_id,
                        status,
                        (SELECT count(*) FROM active_call_statuses WHERE active_call_id = :id) AS total 
                    FROM 
                        active_call_statuses"),
                    ['id' => $activeCall->parent_call_id])
                ->whereIn('status',"('in-progress', 'completed', 'ringing', 'answered', 'busy', 'failed', 'no-answer')")
                ->where("active_calls.parent_call_id", $activeCall->parent_call_id);
```

which resulted in:

```
[2018-03-19 12:33:45] local.ERROR: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() at C:\\wamp64\\www\\Stage\\LanthopusX\\voip\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php:763)
```

Comment: What you are using with `\DB` is a wrapper for raw SQL queries. Eloquent maps the models. They are not the same thing

Comment: I know that, but what i want to do is get rid of the `\DB` and map it to the eloquent model. but right now the query doesn't work at all. it doesn't matter either if `\DB` is used or it's converted to an eloquent model, I would like it to work, PREFERABLY as an eloquent model. but if it returns the data i'm happy either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ActiveCallStatus::leftJoin('active_calls', 'active_calls.parent_call_id', '=', 'active_call_statuses.active_call_id')
    ->whereIn('status', ['in-progress', 'completed', 'ringing', 'answered', 'busy', 'failed', 'no-answer'])
    ->where('active_calls.parent_call_id', $activeCall->parent_call_id)
    ->select('status')
    ->selectRaw('(SELECT count(*) FROM active_call_statuses WHERE active_call_id = ?) AS total', [$activeCall->parent_call_id])
    ->get();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I noticed my errors in my code eventually too but after a whole day of staring at my 700 lines of code in the controller all errors i got slowly got blurry so I missed some here and there xD